# Spring boot + JPA + Hibernate 3 related tables

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

im trying to join 3 tables: Client Motorcycle MotorcycleBrand
when i made the request i cant get the brand(MotorcycleBrand)
Client Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="client")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer clientId;
    @Column(name="name", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Motorcycle> motorcycles = new ArrayList<>();
```

Motorcycle Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="motorcycle")
public class Motorcycle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer motorcycleId;
    @Column(name="model", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String model;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional =false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientId")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Client client;


    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="motorcycleBrandId")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private MotorcycleBrand motorcycleBrand;
```

MotorcycleBrand Entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="motorcycleBrand")
public class MotorcycleBrand {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer motorcycleBrandId;
    @Column(name="brand", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String brand;
```

IClientRepository

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Client c")
List<Client> findAllClients();
```

the response using postman is:

```json
[
    {
        "clientId": 1,
        "name": "jon doe",
        "cel": "+1234124123",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "createAt": "2023-07-23",
        "comment": "",
        "motorcycles": [
            {
                "motorcycleId": 1,
                "model": "ybr125",
                "chassisNumber": "chasisnumber123",
                "motorNumber": "motornumber123",
                "kilometers": 123.0,
                "patent": "877jyy",
                "imageUrl": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "clientId": 2,
        "name": "juan de los palotes",
        "cel": "111111111",
        "email": "mj@mail.com",
        "createAt": "2023-07-23",
        "comment": "test",
        "motorcycles": [
            {
                "motorcycleId": 2,
                "model": "ns200",
                "chassisNumber": "chasisnumber123",
                "motorNumber": "motornumber123",
                "kilometers": 123.0,
                "patent": "abc123",
                "imageUrl": ""
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The relation must be OneToMany from client to Motorcycle and i suppose ManyToOne from Motorcyce to MotorcycleBrand
I tryied to modify this using OneToOne without success

Comment: JSON does exactly what you told it to `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` what do you think this does... Hint the `WRITE_ONLY` is a pretty good give away.